# MQL4 - ERROR 4111 when calling OrderSend() method

Tags: algorithmic-trading, mql4, metatrader4, mql5

I am trying to place order, but my call to `OrderSend()` method <sup>( https://docs.mql4.com/trading/ordersend )</sup>
is failing:

> `2016.08.01 00:51:09.710   2016.07.01 01:00  s EURUSD,M1: OrderSend error 4111`

```
void OnTick() {
    if (  OrdersTotal() == 0 ){
          int   result =  OrderSend( NULL, OP_SELL, 0.01, Bid, 5, 0, Bid - 0.002, NULL, 0, 0, clrGreen );
          if (  result <  0 ) Print( "Order failed #", GetLastError() );
          else                Print( "Order success" );
    }
}
```

Do you know what am I doing wrong please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Let's dis-assemble the `OrderSend()` call first:

```
int result = OrderSend( NULL,             // string:      _Symbol,
                        OP_SELL,          // int:         OP_SELL,
                        0.01,             // double:      NormalizeLOTs( nLOTs ),
                        Bid,              // double:      NormalizeDouble( Bid, Digits ),
                        5,                // int:         slippagePOINTs,
                        0,                // double:      {       0 | NormalizeDouble( aSlPriceTARGET, Digits ) },
                        Bid-0.002,        // double:      {       0 | NormalizeDouble( aTpPriceTARGET, Digits ) },
                        NULL,             // string:      {    NULL | aBrokerUnguaranteedStringCOMMENT },
                        0,                // int:         {       0 | aMagicNUMBER },
                        0,                // datetime:    {       0 | aPendingOrderEXPIRATION },
                        clrGreen          // color:       { clrNONE | aMarkerCOLOR }
                        );
```

For one's further peace-of-mind, **one ought always normalise all the values, that have some restrictive handling** on the **`MQL4`**-side ( prices + lot ( quantised ) values -- as these are not continuous values in R domain, **but rather quantum-stepped:**

**prices:** having a `0.00001` or `0.0001` or `0.001` or `0.01` or `0.1` or `1.0` etc. stepping,

**lot-volumes:** being more restricted by the Broker-specific settings, per instrument, of three key values, all allowable volume sizes have to meet:
 `[aMinLOTs<=, +aMinLotSTEP, <=aMaxLOTs]` **`+`** a proper digit normalisation
**~** thus a **`double NormalizeLOTs( aProposedVOLUME ) {...}`** is a handy tool for a seamless implementation of both parts of this need.

---

### `Error 4111:`

There are a few other barriers, that prevent your <kbd>**`MetaTrader Terminal 4`**</kbd> from running your code smooth:

> **`4111`**
>        **`ERR_SHORTS_NOT_ALLOWED`**
>        **`Shorts are not allowed. Check the Expert Advisor properties`**

```
 if (  !TerminalInfoInteger( TERMINAL_TRADE_ALLOWED ) ) 
        Alert( "Check if automated trading is allowed in the terminal settings!" ); 
 else  if (  !MQLInfoInteger( MQL_TRADE_ALLOWED ) )
             Alert( "Automated trading is forbidden in the program settings for ",
                    __FILE__
                    );
```

This instructs user to revise <kbd>`MetaTrader Terminal 4`</kbd> settings,
under **`MT4 -> Tools -> Options -> ExpertAdvisor`** Tab
and Broker-side Trading Instrument conditions, where shorting for some instruments may be restricted in general, or just for certain Account type(s).

```
 if (  !AccountInfoInteger( ACCOUNT_TRADE_EXPERT ) )
        Alert( "Automated trading is forbidden for the account",
                AccountInfoInteger( ACCOUNT_LOGIN ),
               " at the trade server side. Contact Broker's Customer Care Dept."
               );
```

For more details, printScreens and demonstrated programmatic handling of this group of both **`Terminal`**-side / **Broker**-side barriers: ref.-> MQL4 Reference / MQL4 programs / Trade Permission